# Why is my font not being updated when I call label.setFont()?

Tags: javafx, fonts, label, jlabel

I have a JavaFX program that uses labels. I've loaded two custom fonts and I want to make the label switch between the two fonts.

However, when I call `label.setFont(font2)`, the font doesn't change. I switched the order to verify that both fonts worked, and they do. No errors are thrown, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

I Googled around but I couldn't find any other people having this problem. I found some people unable to load custom fonts at all, but nobody seemed to be having trouble switching to a working font.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be with the font itself. I had duplicated an existing font using FontForge and made some minor changes to it. However, I didn't change the font's "Font Name", "Family Name", or "Unique ID".

Because of this, the setFont function wasn't working. My guess is that it checks the two fonts' unique IDs and doesn't actually switch the font if they match. This seems like buggy/bad behavior to me, although the core problem was that I hadn't saved the second font properly.